# How can I make a link that NTFS supports?

Tags: windows-7, samba, ntfs, symbolic-link

When I make a link so that someone can access a file over the network directly, and then copy it across, I get the following error:

```
There was an error copying the file into smb://ostrich/users/Public/Website.
Symlinks not supported by backend
```

I know this is because NTFS uses different links (the `mklink` command as opposed to the `ln` command), but how can I make a link for NTFS - can you use `mklink` on Ubuntu?

Comment: Show us, in the question, the commands you typed to get the error.

Comment: I dragged it from one nautilus window to the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you use the `-n` option.

```
ln -n /home/tim/Website/family/name/index.html /home/tim
```

and then copy across to the samba share.

Comment: is this an answer to you question? I am confused.

Comment: @rich yes it is